# Spring Data read MongoDB password from a vault or other protected source

Tags: java, security, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, credentials

Currently, my spring-boot application connects to a local MongoDB without credentials. To be able to install it at a customer I need to provide the capability to use username and password for the DB connection. I am using the application.properties file, which currently contains only these 3 lines related to the database:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=myApp
```

There would be these two additional ones:

```
spring.data.mongodb.username
spring.data.mongodb.password
```

But of course, I don't want to have the password in plain text within this file, or even worse in our git. One option would be to provide them as a parameter with a start script but then again it would be readable as plain text in the process details.

I've seen some encryption in the properties file using [Jasypt](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt), but I don't understand how this approach would work in my case. I never explicitly use these properties as they are automatically taken by spring to do the connection.

What would be the safest approach?

Answer (score 7):

## TL; DR

It depends on your security/risk profile, which method is acceptable.

## The longer read

Your question is: What would be the safest approach?

A simple answer to this question is not storing the password anywhere but letting an operator type it in. Obviously, that's not the answer you're looking for as with servers in data centers or even VM's in the cloud this approach isn't feasible.

To understand what method is safe enough and which one is acceptable, it's important to understand your organizational context, its willingness to accept risk and the resulting consequence which is the requirement for handling secrets. This evaluation can result that for one organization it may be fine storing credentials in plain text (because the environment is secured or there's a low threat associated on exposed secrets), others require encryption with proper key management and auditing.

You're already describing that storing credentials in Git isn't a proper option. So I assume that you're looking towards a method that protects the actual secret in some way. Protection can happen on different levels:

- Storing secrets in a protected place with access control applied

  - An environment variable on a host that is access protected
  - An access-controlled file with protected by permissions
- Storing secrets in the encrypted form

  - Encrypting the value and storing it in a file. Here you need to consider who has access to this file and what about key management. Introduces sort of chicken and egg problem
  - Encrypting the value and storing it in memory. Still, you need to solve the key management issue.
- Retrieving the secret from a trusted source

  - Credentials are typed in by an ops person (Not really feasible)
  - Asking a service to provide you with the credential. The remote service protects the secret and allows you/your application to ask for the secret.

There are potentially more possibilities but let's stick with these for now. One aspect that is associated with the above-mentioned possibilities is the transport of the credential from the source to the target destination. Transport typically spans over one to many parties and each of these parties need to be trusted in some way (i.e. you must make sure a certain party does not divulge your credentials). This pattern is also known as chain of trust. If every hop in the chain of trust is known, to not expose your credentials, then you can react with a particular protection pattern to this context. If you find a weak link that elevates the risk of exposure (e.g. a public folder, Lookup by an operator), then you again need to increase the level of protection according to your needs.

Having all that said, let's take a look which possibilities you have with Spring Boot to apply protection of secrets:

### Environment variables

You can store configuration using environment variables or system properties. The aspect of volatility distinguishes from a persistent (e.g., file-based) storage. Variables can be set before/upon application startup.

Example for environment variables:

```
export SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_USERNAME=…
export SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PASSWORD=…

java -jar my-app.jar
```

Examples for system properties:

```
java -jar my-app.jar -Dspring.data.mongodb.username=… -Dspring.data.mongodb.password=…
java -jar my-app.jar --spring.data.mongodb.username=… --spring.data.mongodb.password=…
```

Please note that environment variables/command lines can be introspected by the `/proc` file system and tools like `ps`

See the reference documentation on [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for further details.

### Encrypted Configuration Properties

Spring Cloud comes with crypto support for individual properties. You can encrypt selected properties with different keys and key types (symmetric, asymmetric). This approach allows you to select properties that should be encrypted without the need to encrypt the whole file.

Example for environment variables:

*application.properties*

```
spring.data.mongodb.password={cipher}FKSAJDFGYOS8F7GLHAKERGFHLSAJ
```

Please note this approach introduces the requirement of property key management.

See the reference documentation on [Spring Cloud Config Encryption and Decryption](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption) for further details.

### Application-controlled secrets

Configuration Properties in Spring Boot are obtained from the `Environment` and provided by `PropertySource`s. You can contribute either properties or an entire `PropertySource` before spinning up Spring Boot.

Example of adding a `PropertySource`:

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
app.addInitializers(new ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(…);
    }
});

app.run(args);
```

Example of adding a property:

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("spring.data.mongodb.password", "…"));

app.run(args);
```

### Remote Configuration Properties

Spring Cloud Config allows you to centralize configuration that is served by Spring Cloud Config Server. Properties are no longer stored locally, but served from a config service that can be secured differently than your application protection level. To setup Spring Cloud Config Server, you need an additional service and integrate the client dependency in your application.

Please note that this approach does not solve the overall problem, but just moves it into someone else's responsibility.

See the reference documentation on [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_server) for further details.

### Using Secrets Management

If you can afford a Secrets Management, such as HashiCorp Vault, CredHub, Azure KeyVault, Kubernetes Secrets, then you can leverage the features of your platform/Secrets Management system to apply protection to your credentials.

Secret Management systems typically handle encryption, auditing, and access control for you. These systems keep an encrypted copy of the credential. Once you request the credential (typically over TLS secured connections), the system checks whether you/your application is allowed to access that secret or not.

Some of these systems also provide dynamic secrets. Dynamic secrets are generated for a particular application instance upon demand. If your application wants to connect to MongoDB, the secrets management system is going to create a credentials pair and server these to your application. When your application stops, then the secrets management system is going to revoke the credentials.

See the reference documentation on [Spring Cloud Vault](https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/docs/current/reference/html/) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer! I agree that it depends on the risk you want to take. In our case this is probably dependent on our customers. So I need to introduce something for our hosted service and have different options for self hosting at the customer which relies on their needs.

Answer (score 0):

One addendum to the answer from @mp911de:

There is a second file option in Spring Boot: You are able to provide an additional file to overwrite the standard config, by providing either a ENV variable `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION` to a file or adding it as a command property like `spring.config.additional-location`, see [Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

This could give you the opportunity to add the credentials via some file base secret deployment (eg. Kubernetes secrets used as a volumeMounts, Puppet/Chef/Ansible based secret deployment etc.).